How to ask user for location permission with Geolocator in iOS?
as seen in a lot of other questions, I can't make the Geolocator package return a permission.granted when working with iOS. With android everything works fine but with iOS it always returns permission.permanentlyDenied, and it doesn't even show the prompt to allow location. I am using permission_handler: ^11.3.1 and geolocator: ^13.0.1.
I am requesting the location in the following way:
Future<void> requestLocationAccess() async {
    final status = await Permission.location.request();

    if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      Permission.location.onPermanentlyDeniedCallback(() {});
    }
    state = state.copyWith(location: status);

    _checkPermissionState(status); // this functions sends user to openSettingsScreen 
  }

here's my Info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>SAGA</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>pjecz_saga_app</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceso a la camara para tomar fotografías.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceso a la galería para seleccionar fotografías.</string>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceso a la biblioteca multimedia</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceso a su ubicación para agregarlas a las fotografías.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceso a su ubicación para agregarlas a las fotografías.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceso a su ubicación para agregarlas a las fotografías.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceso a su ubicación para agregarlas a las fotografías.</string>
    <key>NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary</key>
    <dict>
        <key>TemporaryPreciseAccuracy</key>
        <string>La aplicación requiere acceso a la ubicación precisa para vincularla con la fotografía.</string>
    </dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>sms</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

here's my Podfile, you can see there's a lot of code commented because I've tried a lot of stuff and can't get it to work.
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
#       config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
#     end
#   end
# end



# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     if target.name == "geolocator_apple"
#       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
#         config.build_settings ['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 
#         'BYPASS_PERMISSION_LOCATION_ALWAYS=1',
#         'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
#         'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
#         'PERMISSION_LOCATION_WHENINUSE=1',
#         'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1'
#       ]
#       end
#     end
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end

# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    
#     # Permisos específicos para geolocator_apple
#     # if target.name == "geolocator_apple"
#     #   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
#     #     config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)',
#     #       'BYPASS_PERMISSION_LOCATION_ALWAYS=1',
#     #       'PERMISSION_LOCATION_WHENINUSE=1',
#     #       'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
#     #       'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
#     #       'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
#     #       'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1'
#     #     ]
#     #   end
#     # end

#     # Configuración común para todos los targets
#     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
#       config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
#     end

#     # Ajustes adicionales de Flutter
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # You can remove unused permissions here
      # for more information: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/main/permission_handler_apple/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',
        
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendarFullAccess
        'PERMISSION_EVENTS_FULL_ACCESS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

        ## The 'PERMISSION_LOCATION' macro enables the `locationWhenInUse` and `locationAlways` permission. If
        ## the application only requires `locationWhenInUse`, only specify the `PERMISSION_LOCATION_WHENINUSE`
        ## macro.
        ##
        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION_WHENINUSE=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
        'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
        'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
        'PERMISSION_ASSISTANT=0',
      ]

    end
  end
end


turns out: in iOS you can't ask the user for the location like that!! you need to ask for locationWhenInUse for it to prompt the user for the permission. that way it won't automatically return permanentlyDenied.
it's nothing related to the info.plist or the Podfile (afaik), it's just the way you must ask for the permission.
here's the function that worked for me, in both ios and android.
  Future<void> requestLocationWhenInUseAccess() async {
    final status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
    state = state.copyWith(locationWhenInUse: status);

    _checkPermissionState(status);
  }
}

hope anyone that comes across this problem can easily solve it this way.
